# set type dynamically using Createmany

Tags: c#, oop, elasticsearch

I have different types of documents that are derived from a base type called Topic. I'd like to use:

```
  Client.Bulk(b => b.CreateMany(documents)
```

to be able to process all the documents with a single call to Bulk, how can I set the type for each document?

Here is a snippet of code:

```
   public IEnumerable<IBulkResponse> CreateBulkTopics(IEnumerable<Topic> topics)
    {
       var results = new List<IBulkResponse>();

       results.Add(IndexDocuments(TopicFactory.ConvertDrugsToDocuments(topics)));

       results.Add(IndexDocuments(TopicFactory.ConvertTreatmentSummariesToDocuments(topics)));

       return results; 
    }

    public IBulkResponse IndexDocuments(IEnumerable<Common.Elastic.Models.Topic> documents)
    {
        return ElasticConnector.Client.Bulk(b => b.CreateMany(documents));
    }
```

The problem at this minute is all the documents are being stored as "topic" as opposed to the derived types such as drugs and treatmentsummaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many types inherit from `Topic`? Are they constant and small? Then something like this can help. Lets say TopicA and TopicB inherit from Topic:

```
public IEnumerable<IBulkResponse> IndexDocuments(IEnumerable<Common.Elastic.Models.Topic> documents)
{
    yield return ElasticConnector.Client.Bulk(b => b.CreateMany(documents.OfType<TopicA>()));
    yield return ElasticConnector.Client.Bulk(b => b.CreateMany(documents.OfType<TopicB>()));
}
```

and then in `CreateBulkTopics`:

```
results.AddRange(IndexDocuments(....
```

Of course this is only effective if the number of subclasses is small and available to this code. Otherwise, you can use reflection to achieve the same result. The sample code is a bit more complex, but tell me if you need it. Also, this will degrade performance in case the number of subclasses is very high, as it will send each type in a separate request to Bulk api. I can think of no better apprach in the client.

EDIT: This is how you do it using reflection:

```
class MyClass
{
    public IBulkResponse IndexDocuments<T>(IEnumerable<Topic> documents)
        where T : Topic
    {
        var derived = documents.OfType<T>();
        return ElasticConnector.Client.Bulk(b => b.CreateMany(derived));
    }

    public IEnumerable<IBulkResponse> IndexDocumentsByType(IEnumerable<Topic> documents)
    {
        var groups = documents.GroupBy(x => x.GetType());
        var method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(nameof(IndexDocuments)); //prior to c#6, typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("IndexDocuments")
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(group.Key);
            var result = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { group });
            yield return result as IBulkResponse;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var documents = new Topic[] { new TopicA(), new TopicA(), new TopicB(), new Topic() };
        var result = new MyClass().IndexDocumentsByType(documents);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count()); //writes 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a brilliant solution! Potentially there will be about 12 derived classes from Topic. I'm curious how I can use reflection to achieve the same result, any chance I could see the sample code please?

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the answer with a reflection sample. There are lots of ways to do it, but the sample can show the idea

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it using a generic class:

```
  public class IndexOperations<T> where T:Topic
    {
      public ElasticConnector ElasticConnector { get; set; }

      public IndexOperations(ElasticConnector elasticConnector)
        {
            ElasticConnector = elasticConnector;
        }

      public IBulkResponse CreateMany(IEnumerable<T> t)
        {
            return ElasticConnector.Client.Bulk(b => b.CreateMany(t));
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
    var documents = TopicFactory.ConvertToDocuments(topics);

    SaveDrugs(documents);

    public IBulkResponse SaveDrugs(IEnumerable<Common.Elastic.Models.Topic> documents)
    {
        var indexOperations = new IndexOperations<Drug>(ElasticConnector);
        return indexOperations.CreateMany(documents.OfType<Drug>());
    }
```